# Is it rigorous if the limit of a function depends on the variable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

For example:
if $x$ is large enough, $\ln(1+x)$ approaches to $\ln(x)$ because
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\ln(1+x)-\ln(x))=0$$
Then Can we state that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \ln(1+x)=\lim_{x\to \infty} \ln(x)$$
Is it a rigorous statement or not?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with $=$ in $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(1+x)=\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(x)$ and whether $\infty$ is an actual existing object.

Comment: And I don't see the relation between the title and the question. A function is a function and the limit of a function at a point is what it is, there's no need to bring variables into the mix.

Comment: The limit cannot depend on the variable that is approaching something, but that's no reason why two limits cannot be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such statements are perfectly well formed, but it doesn't mean what you want it to. It merely says that those limits are equal - but both those limits are $\infty$. All the information that that tells us is both functions grow arbitrarily large - that is, we could equally well say
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(1+x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^x$$
even though those two functions grow at tremendously different rates. A limit is an operation that takes in a function and outputs a number. It discards all information about rate of convergence and whatnot (i.e. everything captured in the parameter $x$, which does not exist outside the limit), so it is not effective to express the notion of two functions getting arbitrarily close through two limits.

That said, we would be perfectly well justified in saying that $f$ and $g$ "approach each other" if
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)-g(x)=0.$$
However, it's not a perfectly natural notion - we could also say $f$ and $g$ do so if
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$
which is a weaker notion, but still looks valid. We might only care
$$0<\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\infty$$
(which is the idea behind the very commonly used [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)). The idea is that the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)-g(x)=0$ is expressing a very precise, but not wholly natural condition - so it's much better to write it out explicitly, as otherwise it is unclear exactly what you mean by "approach each other".

Comment: As indicated in the comments in my question, if we argue that when $x \to \infty$, $\ln(1+x)=\ln(x)$, I wonder whether this statement is rigorous enough or not?

Comment: Perfectly well formed? Not all the time, not in calculus. Saying $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ is an abbreviation for a specific formula, the $=$ sign is not an actual equality. And saying $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(1+x)=\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(x)$ only makes sense if $\infty$ is an actual object (i.e. when you're working on the extended real line - not something it's usually done in calculus) (...)

Comment: (...) or if you interpret $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(1+x)=\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(x)$ as an abbreviation of $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(1+x)=\infty \land \lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \ln(x)=\infty$. But this is something that must be defined this way, otherwise it is meaningless as per the usual meanings of the entities involved.

Comment: @NalRa No. Same reason as above- I don't know if you're trying to express $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\ln(1+x)-\ln(x)=0$ or $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\ln(x)}=1$ or even "for all large enough $x$, $\ln(1+x)=\ln(x)$". You could happily define some notation for the idea (like you could define $f(x)\equiv_{x\rightarrow c} g(x)$ to mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)-g(x)=0$), but if you're using limits, you have to express it as the limit of the difference - limits are a precise concept, and do not themselves capture the concept you want.

Comment: @GitGud It does not make sense to me to make that distinction (even if it is often taught that way). If we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$, I already see an $\infty$, so it had better be in the domain we're talking about. Sure, you can define it differently, but then you end up with four definitions of $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=k$ on whether $c$ and $k$ are infinite - but given that working in the extended reals is equivalent, it makes far more sense to use them rather than to take such pains to avoid the very natural notion of $\infty$.

Comment: @Meelo Don't blame, it's how it's usually done. It's not my decision. And pedagogically the distinction is very important.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is true as it can be written in this form -

$ \lim_{x \to \infty} log\left(\dfrac{1 + x}{x}\right)$

$ = \lim_{x \to \infty} log\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

$ = log1 = 0$